# How can I use this in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this for a class assignment and I know there has to be a better way of writing it. Maybe some kind of loop that gets the inputs and labels? I'm repeating a lot here and it seems better to minify this if possible.

```
function checkEmptyFields() {

if(formName.value === "") {        
    formLabels[0].classList.add("has-errors");
    formLabels[0].innerHTML = "Name is required *";
    formName.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
} else {
    formLabels[0].classList.remove("has-errors");
    formLabels[0].innerHTML = "Name";
    formName.style.borderBottomColor = "green";
}

if(formEmail.value === "") {
    formLabels[1].classList.add("has-errors");
    formLabels[1].innerHTML = "Email is required *";
    formEmail.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
} else {
    formLabels[1].classList.remove("has-errors");
    formLabels[1].innerHTML = "Email";
    formEmail.style.borderBottomColor = "green";
}

if(formNumber.value === "") {
    formLabels[2].classList.add("has-errors");
    formLabels[2].innerHTML = "Phone is required *";
    formNumber.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
} else {
    formLabels[2].classList.remove("has-errors");
    formLabels[2].innerHTML = "Phone";
    formNumber.style.borderBottomColor = "green";
}

if(formMessage.value === "") {
    formLabels[3].classList.add("has-errors");
    formLabels[3].innerHTML = "message is required *";
    formMessage.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
} else {
    formLabels[3].classList.remove("has-errors");
    formLabels[3].innerHTML = "Email";
    formMessage.style.borderBottomColor = "green";
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe giving out your html code will help the others to understand your code more.

Comment: If this code works, you wrote it, and you want a review of all of your code, this **may** be on-topic on [codereview.se], but please do read their help center.

Comment: You can use a for loop to loop from 0 to 3 (inclusive). You can then replace your indexes with your iterating variable from your `for` loop (ie: `i`). Doing this will allow you to remove your duplicated if-statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
fields = [{
 'name': formName,
 'index': 0,
 'css-error': "has-errors",
 'innerHtml': "Name",
 'innerHtml-error': "Name is required *",
 'borderBottomColor ': "green", //Or you can hardcode it in the loop itself.
 'borderBottomColor-error': "red"
},
 ....
]

for(var i=0; i < fields.length; i++) {
 var field = fields[i];
 if(field.name.value == "") {
   formLabels[field.index].classList.add(field.css);
   formLabels[field.index].innerHTML = field.innerHtml-error;
   field.name.style.borderBottomColor = field.borderBottomColor-error ;
 } else {
   formLabels[field.index].classList.remove(field.css);
   formLabels[field.index].innerHTML = field.innerHtml;
   field.name.style.borderBottomColor = field.borderBottomColor ;
 }
}
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the other answers, you have to maintain a list of the fields that need validation and you have to keep that list in sync with the HTML, so you are duplicating data.  Also, just FYI, good answers on Stack Overflow should not just provide a solution. They should explain how the solution works and what the code does. "Try this" is not a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create arrays for both the **controls** and the **control names**, and process them together with the `formLabels` array that you already have, in a *for*-loop that goes from 0 to length (not inclusive), like this:

```
function checkEmptyFields() {

    var controls = [formName, formEmail, formNumber, formMessage];
    var controlNames = ["Name", "Email", "Phone", "Message"];

    for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
        if(controls[i].value === "") {        
            formLabels[i].classList.add("has-errors");
            formLabels[i].innerHTML = controlNames[i] + " is required *";
            controls[i].style.borderBottomColor = "red";
        } else {
            formLabels[i].classList.remove("has-errors");
            formLabels[i].innerHTML = controlNames[i];
            controls[i].style.borderBottomColor = "green";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but then you've got to maintain the arrays if the form changes. And, you're having to manage loop counters as well.

Comment: The original is hardcoded for 4 controls + their names, so is this but in a way that is already much easier to maintain. A slightly more generic way could be to feed all 3 arrays as parameters, but that did not seem to be the point of the question.

Comment: How is this easy to maintain? If you add or remove a field, you've got two arrays that need to be updated and the two arrays need to be kept in sync. You're also duplicating data (the name of the field is now in HTML and in JavaScript). At the very least, you should use an object, rather than an array to store the data, but even then you've still got to update the object as fields get added/removed. A better solution is to make it work no matter what the fields and field names are. See my solution which does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an additional function to check one field:

```
    function checkEmptyField(field, ind, msg, errmsg) {

    if(field.value === "") {        
        formLabels[ind].classList.add("has-errors");
        formLabels[ind].innerHTML = errmsg;
        field.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
    } else {
        formLabels[ind].classList.remove("has-errors");
        formLabels[ind].innerHTML = msg;
        field.style.borderBottomColor = "green";
    }
    }
```

Then you can call it

```
function checkEmptyFields() {
 checkEmptyField(formName,0,"Name","Name is required *");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know about and understand for loops you can simply loop over 2 arrays of data like this:

```
function checkEmptyFields() {

    formArray = [formName, formEmail, formNumber, formMessage];
    labelArray = ["Name", "Email", "Phone", "Message"];

    for (let i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
        if(formArray[i].value === "") {        
            formLabels[i].classList.add("has-errors");
            formLabels[i].innerHTML = labelArray[i] + " is required *";
            formArray[i].style.borderBottomColor = "red";
        } else {
            formLabels[i].classList.remove("has-errors");
            formLabels[i].innerHTML = labelArray[i];
            formArray[i].style.borderBottomColor = "green";
        }
    }
}
```

if not then you can read about them here:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Yeah, but then you've got to maintain the arrays if the form changes. And, you're having to manage loop counters as well.

Comment: adding some extra data to an array isn't that challenging. Also I think the person asking the question is maybe looking for a simpler solution than the one you have provided, as good as it is. What I have said is a good start when learning about loops, the person is clearly a student and may not be as advanced as you think they are

Comment: I understand, but this kind of solution is not scaleable. It's not that adding items to an array is difficult, it's that the solution requires maintenance, which can lead to problems. I think it's better to teach better patterns from the start because newbies tend to take what works (good or bad) and form habits from there.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have roughly the same code in more than one place, you should stop and rethink your approach as you are doing here.

If you give each of the HTML elements that need to be validated a common class, you can then create a node list (collection/array) that contains them. Then you can loop over that collection and perform the same test (written only once) on each item and act accordingly.

Also, I'm not quite sure what you are doing with `.innerHTML`, but don't use that when the text you are working with doesn't have any HTML in it. `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Instead, use `.textContent` when there is no HTML.

```js
// Get all the form fields that need validation into an Array
let fields = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".validationNeeded"));

// Set up form submit event handler
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", checkEmptyFields);

function checkEmptyFields(event) {
  let validCount = fields.length; // Holds the number of valid fields

  // Loop over the array
  fields.forEach(function(field){
    if(field.value === ""){
      field.previousElementSibling.classList.add("has-errors-label");    // style the label
      field.classList.add("has-errors-field"); // style the field
      field.classList.remove("valid-field");   // style the field        
      validCount--; // Decrease the count of valid fields
    } else {
      field.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("has-errors-label"); // style the label
      field.classList.remove("has-errors-field"); // style the field
      field.classList.add("valid-field");         // style the field       
    }
  });
  
  // Check to see if the form should be submitted
  if(validCount !== fields.length){
    event.preventDefault();  // Cancel the form's submission
  }
}
```

```css
.row {margin-bottom:5px; }
.has-errors-label { color:red; }
.has-errors-field { outline:1px solid red; }
.valid-field      { outline:1px solid green; }
```

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="userName">Name: </label>
    <input class="validationNeeded" name="userName" id="userName">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input class="validationNeeded" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
    <input class="validationNeeded" name="phone" id="phone">
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```